# Web Map Service vs Cloud Optimised GeoTIFF (COG) Vs GeoTIFF

Tags: wms, geotiff-tiff, tiles, image-pyramids, cloud-optimized-geotiff

I'm looking into COG's to look if a COG would help me improve a application in serving or using GeoTiffs.

I've got a working WMS, which gets an input of coordinates and then looks at a tiled GeoTIFF for the right tiles. When it has the tiles it needs it creates a images and sends this through the service to the client to be served. The tiled GeoTIFF has also 6 levels of overviews/pyramids.

Now my confusion. As I understand, what a COG and a GeoTIFF differentiates from each other are tiling and overviews. Plus something extra within the HTTP protocol. Byte serving AKA Streaming.

While I use tiled GeoTIFFs with overviews, I understand these are still not yet official 'COG's'. I understand that is has no more further use within my Web Map service, as that one serves data to the client.

But for other function I would like to create (Profile tools etc.) Would a COG give me more pro's than a tiled GeoTIFF with overviews? Or are they basically the same?

Comment: related Q ~ https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/448891/what-is-the-reason-for-using-geoserver-to-provide-access-to-cloud-optimized-geot